# How do I handle models that should have one and only one row in their database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, content-management-system

It is common for customers to want to have control over their application without having to go back to the developer. In these cases, they usually request a simple CMS where they can edit otherwise static parts of their application. For example:

- Privacy Policy
- Terms of Conditions
- About section
- Contact us section

In a Rails application, it seems cumbersome to make them separate models and controllers, because they are really just text fields (although in my particular case ,the About/Contact Us section can have multiple sections). The controllers are dead simple and relatively unimportant, so they seem like they are just there to clutter up the controllers directory.

I was thinking of some sort of StaticContent model (although this name inherently makes no sense) that can contain all of these strings, but index them by name. So I can do:

```
StaticContent.find_by_name("about")
```

Or something like that, and keep everything in one controller and model - but I still don't like the idea of finding everything by name all of the time. Has anyone ran into a better solution for storing this type of data in the situation I described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on an app once where we had a `Page` model. We used the `friendly_id` gem (https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id) to give them slugs that could serve as both id and uri. So then you'd have:

```
scope '/' do
  resource :pages
end
```

in your routes file and a very simple controller that would just look up by the `:id` parameter (which, however, is a human-readable slug) and render the `page.content` into the layout (for the show action). So for example `/terms` would show your terms & conditions page, `/about` would show the about page, etc. etc.

We used TinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/) as a wysiwyg editor for producing the markup that we stored in the `content` field of the `page` object.

Simple enough, and a nice flexible solution that even allows the creation of brand new `pages`. You could of course easily restrict this to `only: [ :show, :edit, :update ]` and prevent the editing of slugs if you wanted to give them just a few editable pages without allowing them to create/destroy/move them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting the data in a .yml file, e.g.

```
example.yml
 - content_name: privacy_policy
   - title: Privacy Policy  
   - content: blah blah blah
 - content_name: terms_and_conditions
   - title: Terms and Conditions
   - content: blah blah blah blah
```

Add it to your seed_fu and have it seed a generic table with columns content_name, title, content. As for find_by_name I don't see a huge problem with doing that. Using a yml file though should help to solve your issue of how to store this data

Comment: The idea is that the customer can edit these details easily on their own, without any knowledge of YAML, seeding, databases, Rails, servers, etc and without having to rely on developer assistance. That is why many of them request a simple CMS where they can just edit a textarea or something like that.

Comment: I agree though that YML would be nice for storing static content, that is why it is used for translation files and stuff like that. But this is a different story :)